# bitcoind and rollntime support

Tags: bitcoind, getwork

According to this page: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poolservers bitcoind's rollntime support is 'Supported, but not advertised'.  I am taking that to mean that it doesn't provide the X-Roll-NTime header that would advertise this support, but you can increment the ntime value to get extra nonce space and still submit found blocks after doing this.

Is this correct?  If so, what would be the max amount that a mining client can increment the ntime value?

Answer (score 1):

> If so, what would be the max amount that a mining client can increment the ntime value?

`bitcoind` will accept a block and push it out to the network as long as it is valid. Because of that, it's incredibly lenient. Quoting from bitcoin wiki:

> A timestamp is accepted as valid if it is greater than the median timestamp of previous 11 blocks, and less than the network-adjusted time + 2 hours

It almost never matters. Because `bitcoind` is a single-user mining program, it's almost always on the same computer as the mining agent. If the mining agent needs to get more work units, it doesn't use up extra bandwidth.

Comment: Except mining via `getwork` doesn't submit a full block, only the header. Bitcoind still combines it with the transaction data in remembered when creating the work. I'm not sure if this works if you modify the timestamp yourself.

Comment: `I'm not sure if this works if you modify the timestamp` But what else would "Supported, but not adverstised." mean?

Comment: Where do you read that?

Comment: @PieterWuille Look at the bitcoin wiki page, and scroll down to the row that says "rollntime". Click the footnote.